# Attaching data from two different sources based on Timestamps in R

Tags: r

I have received a script that essentially attaches two data sources together based on a time-stamp. It takes very long to run. So I figured to rewrite it. So let me shortly explain the problem:

**THE DATA**

The data that comes from two different sources. Let's call them source **A** and **B** to keep things simple. **Source A** records for example concentration of CO2 of the environment twice every second. **Source B** contains observations of individual cows during a milking in a robot. So the robot records milk yield, for example, from start till end of milking (that's one row in the table).

I quickly wrote a simplified representation of what the data looks like:

```
ori = "2015-03-02"
TimeStamp <- seq(from=20000,to=20025, by = 0.5)
TimeStamp <- as.POSIXct(TimeStamp[-length(TimeStamp)], origin = ori, tz ="GMT")
set.seed(42)
x1 <- 1000:2000
x1 <- sample(50)
sourceA <- data.frame(TimeStamp = TimeStamp, x1 = x1) 

StartTime <- seq(from=20000,to=20025, by = 5)
EndTime <- StartTime + 2
StartTime <- as.POSIXct(StartTime[-length(StartTime)], origin = ori, tz ="GMT")
EndTime <- as.POSIXct(EndTime[-length(EndTime)], origin = ori, tz ="GMT")
set.seed(36)
x2 <- 600:800
x2 <- sample(x2,size = 5)
sourceB <- data.frame(StartTime = StartTime, EndTime = EndTime, x2 = x2)
```

Originally, I wrote a script that would calculate the time difference between the TimeStamp and the StartTime. Then where the difference is 0 attach the data from source **B** to source **A**. I want to avoid looping through the data one-by-one - this will take forever.

What would be a good way to approach this?

**[EDIT]**

I added code to create the desired output:

```
tmp <- NULL
for(i in 1:5){
  tmp <- c(tmp, rep(sourceB$x2[i],6))
  tmp <- c(tmp, rep(0,4))
}
EndResult <- data.frame(TimeStamp = sourceA$TimeStamp, x1 = sourceA$x1, x2 = tmp)
```

Comment: your script doesn't run in R: missing "ori". Please try copy/pasting your whole code in an R console without history (on linux use R --vanilla) before posting. Also merging two different datasets on different time scales can have multiple solutions. You need to give a little more context on what you want to achieve. Typically, what would a line correspond to in your final table?

Comment: What is the desired output? The solution to this problem seems quite simple, but there is just too much text here and its not entirely clear what are you trying to achieve. Also, `sourceA` is just too big (1K rows). We don't need such a big data set in order to reproduce your problem. Please rescale your problem to 20-30 rows and provide how would your expected output should look like in the end.

Comment: Sorry I realize I was bit in a hurry. I updated the data. I don't know how to avoid the text. I wanted to be as clear as possible. I will try to reduce it and add an end result. So essentially source B contains events which I want to attach/merge/couple [insert similar word] to source A based on time stamps. The events can't overlap in source B.

Comment: All you need to do is to explain *what* are you trying to achieve by providing your desired output (on a much smaller data set). This could illustrate your problem way better than this whole text (usually that amount of text scares people).

Comment: yes i realize this. thanks for the advice :)

Comment: I still don't see the desired output...

Comment: @DavidArenburg I updated my question based on your helpful comments and added code for the desired output. I hope its a bit more clear. Cheers

Comment: What are the classes of the dates columns? You just converted them to characters (and then factors) instead of `POSIXct` class. Is that intended? I would recommend to use `format` here at all.

Comment: What are the classes of the dates columns? You just converted them to characters (and then factors) instead of `POSIXct` class. Is that intended? I would recommend *not* to use `format` here at all.

Comment: I used the `POSIXct` to create the dates from the `seq` and then indeed using `format` to turn them into characters. I found this was best way to deal with timestamps. Using `strptime` for example its easy to do calculations with timestamps.

Comment: Don't use format, just leave them `POSIXct` class. My solution works perfectly with this class.

Comment: alright - cheers for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume we are dealing with real `POSIXct` classes here (instead of factor, like you assumingly by accident generated), then the solution is simply using the `foverlaps` function from the `data.table` package which is very efficient for such a task.

First, we will convert both data sets to `data.table` objects, create corresponding start and end dates in both and key the smaller data set. Then, all is left to do is to run the `foverlaps` function. Here are the results of the first 10 lines

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(sourceB), StartTime, EndTime)
setnames(setDT(sourceA)[, EndTime := TimeStamp], "TimeStamp", "StartTime")
(EndResult <- foverlaps(sourceA, sourceB))
#               StartTime             EndTime  x2         i.StartTime x1           i.EndTime
#  1: 2015-03-02 05:33:20 2015-03-02 05:33:22 725 2015-03-02 05:33:20  1 2015-03-02 05:33:20
#  2: 2015-03-02 05:33:20 2015-03-02 05:33:22 725 2015-03-02 05:33:20 47 2015-03-02 05:33:20
#  3: 2015-03-02 05:33:20 2015-03-02 05:33:22 725 2015-03-02 05:33:21 21 2015-03-02 05:33:21
#  4: 2015-03-02 05:33:20 2015-03-02 05:33:22 725 2015-03-02 05:33:21  5 2015-03-02 05:33:21
#  5: 2015-03-02 05:33:20 2015-03-02 05:33:22 725 2015-03-02 05:33:22 17 2015-03-02 05:33:22
#  6:                <NA>                <NA>  NA 2015-03-02 05:33:22 13 2015-03-02 05:33:22
#  7:                <NA>                <NA>  NA 2015-03-02 05:33:23 27 2015-03-02 05:33:23
#  8:                <NA>                <NA>  NA 2015-03-02 05:33:23 23 2015-03-02 05:33:23
#  9:                <NA>                <NA>  NA 2015-03-02 05:33:24  3 2015-03-02 05:33:24
# 10:                <NA>                <NA>  NA 2015-03-02 05:33:24  4 2015-03-02 05:33:24
....
```

Comment: what does the `EndTime := Timestamp` part do exactly?

Comment: I need to generate end date in both data sets, so I just assigned the same date to end and start dates within `sourceA`. Did you try to run this on real data? This should be very fast.

Comment: I am trying to figure out to run it on the real data. will get back to you soon.

Comment: All you have to do is to generate end date in `sourceA` (which is the same as the `TimeStamp`. Then make sure that both data sets have same names for the joining fields (this is the `setnames` part in the third line`), lastly, you need to key (by using `setkey`) `sourceB` by start and end date, and run `foverlaps` when `sourceA` is the first argument and `sourceB` is the second.

Comment: it's not working for me currently. The `TimeStamp`, `StartTime` and `EndTime` are contained in the data.frames. `TimeStamp` in '`sourceA`' and the other two in '`sourceB`'. They are not seperate variables like in the example. I used those to generate the example data.frames.

Comment: Can you provide a `dput(head(sourceA))` and `dput(head(sourceB))`?

Comment: I saw what I did wrong. it seems to work :) give me some time to play around with this. there is a complication I want to introduce.

Comment: @DavidArenburg -- I am not sure why the `EndTime` should be the same as the `TimeStamp`? I am trying to grasp `data.table` because I think I will end up using it for the rest of my data -- its fast!

Comment: They should be the same because you don't want to match by intervals in `sourceA`, rather by row, while the intervals are `sourceB`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg -- I have a another question: This example is for one day, but in fact the real data contains more data from multiple days. Can I put all the `sourceA` datasets from the different days in a  `list()` and same for `sourceB` data, and then run oneline of code over the two lists that does exactly the same as above?

Comment: Can't you just put everything into a single `data.table`?

Comment: Well not sure, the data comes from different places, different days. But I guess it could be possible. However, I would rather keep it separated to avoid too much confusion.

Comment: Were you able to test this on your real data? How it runs compared to your two hours runs? Does it gives the desired result?

Comment: I tested it on a sample of the real data. It runs within seconds :D! It's quite awesome actually -- cheers! Currently, it doesn't give the desired output -- I am still playing around with it. In fact, the desired output is not 100% known. There is indication of desired output -- and they don't match, yet...

Comment: @DavidArenburg -- it works, and gives the desired output! Thanks a lot for being patient with my initally bad question!

Comment: @DavidArenburg -- On closer inspection I realized I am not getting the same result in the example as you. When i run the code for my example data then row 6 also gets joined. In your case it doesn't. Even when I add `mult = "first"`.  This is the same with the real data. I only want the first match to be joined. Do you have any idea why there is a difference in our results? I am using data.table v1.9.4.

Comment: Try installing the development version from Github. It maybe a bug in the older version https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation

Comment: I will try that. What version of data.table were you using then?

Comment: The one I gave you the link to; v 1.9.5